# The res.redirect is called twice in the passport google callback - I cannot trace why

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-google-oauth, passport-google-oauth2

I am using passport.js both for Facebook and Google auth. The Facebook auth strategy is working fine, the res.redirect in the callback is being called only once. But for the google authentication I am at a loss, as it is called twice. I have spent hours trying to debug this and looking into the passport source code, but just cannot find the bug.

My Google auth just gets some contacts from Gmail.

```
app.get('/contacts/google', 
    passport.authenticate('google', { session: false, scope: ['profile', 'email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly'] })
);

app.get('/login/google/callback',

    passport.authenticate('google', { session: false, failureRedirect: '/' }), 
        function(req, res, next) {


           process.nextTick(function() {
              console.log("Right before the googletoken call", req.user);                         
              res.redirect("/users/" + '?googletoken=' + req.user.access_token );               
              });

        }
);
```

Google Strategy

```
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
var googleConfig = require('./googlekeys.js');

module.exports = function(passport) {

    passport.use('google', new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID        : googleConfig.appID,
        clientSecret    : googleConfig.appSecret,
        callbackURL     : googleConfig.callbackUrl,
        profileFields: ['email','profile']
        },

        // google will send back the tokens and profile
        function(access_token, refresh_token, profile, done) {

            process.nextTick(function() {
                //we send the token we receive back so we can use it to get the contacts
                console.log("Before calling the token callback");
                var user = {};
                user.access_token = access_token;
                return done(null, user);     

            });                
        }
    ));
};
```

And here from the console - the problem is that the /users/?googletoken call is made twice, even though the console.log right before is just called once.

```
GET /contacts/google 302 2.739 ms - 0
At the beginning
Before calling the token callback
Right before the googletoken call { access_token: '[GOOGLE TOKEN]' }
GET /login/google/callback?code=[CODE] 302 485.728 ms - 348
GET /users/?googletoken=[GOOGLE TOKEN THAT WAS RECEIVED BACK] 200 2.812 ms - 7791
GET /users/?googletoken=[GOOGLE TOKEN THAT WAS RECEIVED BACK] 304 1.575 ms - -
```

Comment: +1. I wish I could up-vote more than once to draw attention to this issue -- six months later and still no reliable solution or explanation. In my case, the first action (your '/contacts/google') was being called twice, resulting in two simultaneous authentication flows and two attempted callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

After finally thinking about trying in another browser, I found out there is no problem in Safari and Firefox, so it looks like this is a Chrome buck... and from looking at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64810 this is an old one, I am now checking how to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

I have them same problem. But when I looked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45388104/omniauth-oauth-2-0-callback-fires-twice-in-google-chrome) and stop adblock and the problem is fixed.